# How can I reinstall iWork applications after I removed them from my Mac?

Tags: macos, iwork

If I were to say, remove Pages from my Mac, would I be able to reinstall it later from the Mac App Store?

Comment: Sure, why not?  What OS do you have and where did you get Pages (preinstalled, downloaded from MAS, etc)?

Comment: I originally got it as part of iWork '09 and the license has since been transferred to MAS. I have OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 (15G1004)

Comment: If Pages etc. is part of the applications listed in the "Purchases Apps" category in the store you should be able to redownload it.